# Binding ListView to filter selected item from another ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, textbox

I have two `ListView` items in a WPF application that I'm developion. They are both connected to `Datasets` in the `Presenter` ViewModel in my application.

My original idea was to load my `SelectedItem` in my `ListView` into a `TextBox`, and then have that fire off a filter for the second `ListView`

However, I've run into a problem: I want to filter by number, and the `TextBox` only seems to want to take in text. Is there a workaround for this?

Here is my XAML

```
<Grid Margin="5,2,5,2" Height="350">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="TypeView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CashActivityTypes}" Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!--This is the column I want to get -->
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sequence}" Width="75"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Activity Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,2,0,2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence" Width="75"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Activity" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
<Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Sequence, ElementName=TypeView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Adjust Daily Cash Activity" MinWidth="150" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hm, it is called TEXT box for a reason :). Perhaps you could use a converter to parse string to a number, or do a conversion/parsing in your view model. Also, there are a number of numeric textbox controls around which accept only numbers. I'm using XCeed toolkit: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit, perhaps this could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two-way binding on  the 1st listview selectedItem property to VievModel:

```
private <TYPE> _CashActivityTypeSelected;

public <TYPE> CashActivityTypeSelected 
{
get
 {
   return _CashActivityTypeSelected;
 }
set
{
  _CashActivityTypeSelected=value; 
  FilterMySecondCollectionView(value);
 };
```

in xaml:

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding CashActivityTypeSelected, mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="TypeView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CashActivityTypes}" Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!--This is the column I want to get -->
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sequence" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sequence}" Width="75"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Activity Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and then in `FilterMySecondCollectionView(object t)` you can apply whatever filter you want based on selected object.

Comment: I just tried doing that, but, calling the `short` `TypeSequence`, but it's not passing through. How do I get the individual column?

Comment: Doing it this way you will always have the currently selected object  in CashActivityTypeSelected property. CashActivityTypeSelected.Sequence should be your column.

Comment: Trying this at home with a baseball database I'm working on. No dice.